# Access list of dictionaries via loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to get my head around this:

So the task is: Create a function named main. This function should take two arguments, duck_list_1 and duck_list_2. These are two lists of dictionaries containing data about two groups of ducks:

```
duck_list_1 = [{'name': 'Jerome', 'weight': 3.38, 'wingspan': 49.96, 'length': 19.75},
               {'name': 'Ibraheem', 'weight': 3.08, 'wingspan': 50.59, 'length': 20.6},
               {'name': 'Tiana', 'weight': 0.81, 'wingspan': 47.86, 'length': 17.94},
               {'name': 'Lucas', 'weight': 3.33, 'wingspan': 48.27, 'length': 18.77},
               {'name': 'Rickie', 'weight': 4.4, 'wingspan': 51.0, 'length': 20.34}]

duck_list_2 = [{'name': 'Mysha', 'weight': 6.05, 'wingspan': 60.05, 'length': 30.52},
               {'name': 'Ruben', 'weight': 3.99, 'wingspan': 60.36, 'length': 30.46},
               {'name': 'Tara', 'weight': 6.99, 'wingspan': 62.0, 'length': 32.7},
               {'name': 'Shaurya', 'weight': 6.63, 'wingspan': 61.7, 'length': 31.82}]

def main(duck_list_1,duck_list_2):
  return
```

And then create a function named get_data. This function should take two arguments, data and key. Data should be one of the lists of dictionaries shown above and key should be the data that you wish to extract from each dictionary. This function should then return a list of these attributes.

I have the following code, but it only gives me the first name of the first index (first list of a dictionary). Can someone help please?

```
def get_data (data, key):
  for index in range(len(data)):
    for x in data[index]:
      return(data[index][x])

print(get_data(duck_list_2, 0))
```

Comment: Sorry I am confused - where is key used in your function?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're returning. As soon as you return, nothing else is executed. This is how it should be:

```
def get_data (data, key):
  results = []
  for index in range(len(data)):
    for x in data[index]:
      results.append(data[index][x])
  return results

print(get_data(duck_list_2, 0))
```

The above prints:

```
['Mysha', 6.05, 60.05, 30.52, 'Ruben', 3.99, 60.36, 30.46, 'Tara', 6.99, 62.0, 32.7, 'Shaurya', 6.63, 61.7, 31.82]
```

---

Btw, I'm not sure what you're trying to do passing key=`0` into `get_data` as `0` is not a key in any of the dictionaries, but I just followed your lead.

---

Also, since `data[index]` is a dictionary

```
    for x in data[index]:
```

will iterate over the keys of `data[index]`, which is probably not the behavior you want.

---

Have a go trying to fix it using pythontutor.com or thonny.org and if you still can't figure it out, come back.